# PostgreSQL how to cast multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, casting

I have a PostgreSQL DB with a primary key column that is of type `character varying length 32`.
The keys should be a `19 digit integer`, e.g. `1234567891234567891`
I want to do a simple query on the PK column

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE primary_key = 1234567891234567891
```

This gives me the error:

```
operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
```

I can't `CAST` the column to a `bigint` since it's always 19 digits, so instead I'm casting the number to `character varying` type.

However, since I have a long list of keys, I'd prefer a succinct function to cast them all instead of line by line. This is what I have in the meantime:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE primary_key IN (CAST(1234567891234567891 AS character varying), 
                      CAST(1234567891234567892 AS character varying),
                      /* ... so on so forth ... */
                      CAST(1234567891234567899 AS character varying))
```

I'm just a user so I don't have permissions to change the colum type to numeric(19)

Comment: Where does this "*long list of keys*" originate from?

Comment: A CSV file. Records were migrated from Oracle to PostgreSQL and I was given a list of records to spot check comparisons.

Comment: show your complete script, if you are reading from csv exactly what are you doing with it. why not insert the items from file into a varchar column?  i.e..  using quotes `'1234567891234567891'` is different to not using them `1234567891234567891`

Comment: 1) `... WHERE primary_key = '1234567891234567891'`.  2) `WHERE primary_key::bigint = 1234567891234567891` as in `select '1234567891234567891'::bigint = 1234567891234567891; t`. Then adapt the answer from @FrankHeikens, using `bigint` array.

Comment: I'm just opening it in notepad++ and copying the value over to the query. Opening it in Excel doesn't work since the Excel thinks that column is a number it rounds it off. That query is my complete "script". I guess if there is some sort of read_csv function in PostgreSQL that could work too. Will try Frank's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of keys, and cast just once:

```
WHERE primary_key =ANY('{123,456,789}'::text[])
```